# How to bypass YouTube throttling?

Tags: youtube

My school throttles YouTube video content. How can I bypass this? Is it possible via a VPN?

Answer (score 1):

As long as the school is not throttling **all** traffic you could use a VPN or proxy as your traffic would appear to be going to your VPN's IP rather than YouTube's.